# react-native error: expected conv2d_input to have shape [null,32,32,1] but got array with shape [1,32,32,3]

Tags: javascript, python, react-native, tensorflow, expo

I am making an app using react-native-expo.
We tried to recognize objects in conjunction with the camera with the trained model.
In order to use the existing Python code in react-native-expo, I tried to port the code to fit js.
But it wasn't as easy as I thought. please tell me how to solve it.

*python*

```
while True:
 
# READ IMAGE
    success, imgOrignal = cap.read()

    img = np.asarray(imgOrignal)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))
    img = preprocessing(img)
    cv2.imshow("Processed Image", img)
    img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "CLASS: " , (20, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "PROBABILITY: ", (20, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    predictions = model.predict(img)
    classIndex = np.argmax(predictions[0])
    probabilityValue =np.amax(predictions)
   
    if probabilityValue > threshold:
        cv2.putText(imgOrignal,str(classIndex)+" "+str(getCalssName(classIndex)), (120, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA) 
        cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(round(probabilityValue*100,2) )+"%", (180, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)        
    cv2.imshow("Result", imgOrignal)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

*react-native-expo*

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import React, { createRef, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Platform, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import {
  bundleResourceIO,
  cameraWithTensors,
} from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
import { Camera, CameraType } from "expo-camera";

const CAMERA_SIZE = { height: 640, width: 480 };

const App = () => {
  const [signDetector, setSignDetector] = useState<tf.LayersModel>();
  const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);
  const tensorCameraRef = createRef<any>();
  const textureDims =
    Platform.OS === "ios"
      ? { height: 1920, width: 1080 }
      : { height: 1200, width: 1600 };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadModel();
  }, []);

  const loadModel = useCallback(async () => {
    const isAllowedCamera = fn_requestPermisison();
    if (!isAllowedCamera) return;
    console.log("[+] Application started");
    //Wait for tensorflow module to be ready
    await tf.ready();
    console.log("[+] Loading custom mask detection model");
    //Replce model.json and group1-shard.bin with your own custom model
    const modelJson = await require("./assets/AIDatas/model.json");
    const modelWeight = await require("./assets/AIDatas/group1-shard1of1.bin");
    const newSignDetector = await tf.loadLayersModel(
      bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeight)
    );
    console.log("[+] Loading pre-trained face detection model");
    console.log("summary", signDetector?.summary());
    setSignDetector(newSignDetector);
    console.log("[+] Model Loaded");
  }, []);

  const fn_estimateBlazeFace = async (tensorImage: any) => {
    if (signDetector) {
      const predictions: any = await signDetector.predict(tensorImage, {
        batchSize: 3,
      });
      console.log(`[+] [${predictions}]`);
    }
    return true;
  };

  const fn_onReadyTensorCamera = async (
    images: IterableIterator<tf.Tensor3D>
  ) => {
    const loop = async () => {
      if (signDetector !== undefined) {
        const nextImageTensor = tf.image.resizeBilinear(
          images.next().value,
          [32, 32],
          true
        );
        const expandedImageTensor = tf.expandDims(nextImageTensor, 0);

        console.log("expandedImageTensor", expandedImageTensor);
        await fn_estimateBlazeFace(expandedImageTensor)
          .then((isEstimate) => {
            console.log("result", isEstimate);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        setTimeout(() => {
          requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }, 20000);
      }
    };
    loop();
  };

  const fn_requestPermisison = async () => {
    const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      console.log("The camera's permission request was not approved.");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TensorCamera
        ref={tensorCameraRef}
        style={styles.camera}
        type={CameraType.back}
        cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
        cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
        resizeHeight={CAMERA_SIZE.height}
        resizeWidth={CAMERA_SIZE.width}
        resizeDepth={3}
        autorender={true}
        useCustomShadersToResize={false}
        onReady={fn_onReadyTensorCamera}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  camera: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: CAMERA_SIZE.width,
    height: CAMERA_SIZE.height,
  },
});

export default App;
;
```

Comment: Hi, do you want only use model.predict or build model. You can build model from python and load weight and use .predict() by input dataset. They had example here: 
 [Tf.model][1]


  [1]: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#model

Comment: I want use only predict.